# Can I update multiple elasticsearch indices at the same time?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to configure an index or alias in a way that when I send an update (e.g. PUT /names/person/1) to have another index (names_new) also updated?

### Background

I want to implement a re-indexing from the main database in the background while the app is running. Roughly I want to:

1. Have an alias *names_current* to *names_1*
2. Create a new index *names_2* and populate it with data
3. Change the alias *names_current* to point to *names_2*
4. Remove *names_1*

Step 2 takes some hours of time. In this timespan data is changed. The changes will be present in *names_1* but not in *names_2*. When we switch from *names_1* to *names_2* this changes will be lost. I am looking for a solution to that.

My first Idea is to send all updates during step 2 to *names_1* and *names_2*. But that seems very complicated from the apps perspective.